# accent insensitive regex

Tags: jquery, regex, unicode, highlight, diacritics

My code:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
 highlight: function(search){
  var regex = new RegExp('(<[^>]*>)|('+ search.replace(/[.+]i/,"$0") +')','ig');

  return this.html(this.html().replace(regex, function(a, b, c){
   return (a.charAt(0) == '<') ? a : '<strong class="highlight">' + c + '</strong>';
  }));
 }

});
```

I want to highlight letters with accents,
ie:

```
$('body').highlight("cao");
```

should highlight: [ção] OR [çÃo] OR [cáo] OR expre[cão]tion OR [Cáo]tion

How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sole correct way to do this is to first run it through *Unicode Normalization Form D*, canonical decomposition.

You then strip our any Marks that result (`\pM` characters, or perhaps `\p{Diacritic}`, depending), and run your match against the de/un-marked version.

Do not under any circumstances hardcode a bunch of literals. Eek!

*Boa sorte!*

Comment: How can I do that? It's half answer, just pointing to solution!

Answer (score 3):

You need to come up with a table of alternative characters and dynamically generate a regex based on that. For example:

```
var alt = {
  'c': '[cCç]',
  'a': '[aAãÃá]',
  /* etc. */
};

highlight: function (search) {
  var pattern = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < search.length; i++) {
    var ch = search[i];
    if (alt.hasOwnProperty(ch))
      pattern += alt[ch];
    else
      pattern += ch;
  }

  ...
}
```

Then for `search = 'cao'` this will generate a pattern `[cCç][aAãÃá]o`.