# Regex match insensitive to accents

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode

Say I am looking to match the string, "Bogata". I am looking for a regular expression or a short algorithm that would match either the anglicanized "Bogata" or the correct "Bogotá" or even a misspelled "Bógatá".

Similarly, if I am looking to match the string "Sao Paolo", I would want to match both "Sao Paolo" and "São Paolo".

My question is specific to javascript and the RegExp module but a more general solution would be preferable

Comment: possible duplicate of [accent insensitive regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261740/accent-insensitive-regex)

Answer (score 1):

There's a USENET thread [archived by Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/comp.lang.javascript/imqdmInNLwE/PwvuPtRCgUsJ) that discussed some of the issues involved in supporting Unicode in a a regex extension.  In there, Thomas 'PointedEars' Lahn mentioned his version, [jsx.regexp](http://pointedears.de/scripts/regexp.js), which I've never gotten around to analyzing in depth, but which on the surface looks pretty good.  It might be useful to you.